# postgres error role and db doesnt exist after downloading OSX Mavericks

Tags: macos, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rails-postgresql

I restarted my computer recently and after trying to start my db locally with `rails s` I got the following:

```
/Users/example_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in 

`initialize': could not connect to server: 

No such file or directory (PGError)
```

Then I tried to manually start the db by writing:

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
```

And then it said `server starting` So I retyped `rails s` and then I recieved the error:

```
FATAL: role example_name doesn't exist
```

Which was a strange error I never got before so I tried to create the role again and after running rails s again I then got:

```
FATAL:  database "example_db" does not exist (PGError)
```

I don't think I did anything to drop the db so I'm unsure what exactly is going on.

I did `rake db:create:all` and `bundle exec rake db:migrate` and now it works but the DB is empty! how did this happen? this isn't going to empty my production db if I deploy will it?

Comment: Are you sure your original data directory is indeed `/usr/local/var/postgres`?

Comment: @MilenA.Radev /usr/local/var/postgres exists how can I check if its the original data directory? I feel like this has worked in the past

Comment: Well, if you started Postgres manually, pointing it to this directory, obviously that's what you'll get. Search for `postgresql.conf` (or `pg_hba.conf`) in your drives.

Comment: @MilenA.Radev I did `rake db:create:all` and `bundle exec rake db:migrate` and now it works but the DB is empty! how did this happen? this isn't going to empty my production db if I deploy will it?

Comment: @MilenA.Radev `/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var/pg_hba.conf`
`/usr/local/var/postgres/pg_hba.conf` and `/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var/postgresql.conf`
`/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf`

Comment: What probably happened is that it ran an initdb and created a new data directory.  In general it is a good idea to back up your db before upgrading your operating system.  Among other things, the upgrade of PostgreSQL was probably not handled as gracefully as one might like by the OS upgrade.

Comment: OSX doesn't install anything in `/usr/local` at all. In fact `/usr/local` doesn't even exist on an OSX system unless it's created by someone or some third-party package. Homebrew (ab)uses `/usr/local` by default, and other third-party packages will try to put things there. Mavericks upgrade also isn't going to initialize your DB, even if you happen to have one setup. I'd look elsewhere for the root cause.